# Ignore Flake8 "Line too long" error in gitlab CI

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, lint, flake8

I'm using `flake8` in my gitlab CI stage. my `.gitlab-ci.yaml` linting stage looks like this :

```
linting:
  stage: linting
  tags:
    - docker
  before_script:
    - pip3 install flake8
  script:
    - flake8 .
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

Is there a way to ignore the **"line too long"** error when running my pipeline ? Like a conf file to edit ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah you can do it by passing an argument.

```yaml
linting:
  stage: linting
  tags:
    - docker
  before_script:
    - pip3 install flake8
  script:
    - flake8 --ignore=E501 .
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

Comment: Great that works! Thank you :) Is there a way to edit line limit ? which is 79 in flake8.

Comment: Yeah its surprise a other argument `flake8 --max-line-length=120 --ignore=E501 .`